# remote flink job with query to Hive on yarn-cluster error:NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, apache-flink

env: HDP: 3.1.5(hadoop: 3.1.1, hive: 3.1.0), Flink: 1.12.2
Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().build();
    TableEnvironment tblEnv=TableEnvironment.create(settings);

    String name = "myhive";
    String defaultDatabase = "default";
    String hiveConfDir = "/etc/hive/conf";
    HiveCatalog hive = new HiveCatalog(name, defaultDatabase, hiveConfDir);
    tblEnv.registerCatalog("myhive", hive);
    tblEnv.useCatalog("myhive");

    //tblEnv.getConfig().setSqlDialect(SqlDialect.HIVE);
    tblEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users").execute().print();
}
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

error 1:

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: JobMaster for job 35afe414e1dd861c86130ddd031312f2 failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.jobMasterFailed(Dispatcher.java:887) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.dispatcherJobFailed(Dispatcher.java:465) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.handleDispatcherJobResult(Dispatcher.java:444) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobInitializationException: Could not instantiate JobManager.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.lambda$createJobManagerRunner$5(Dispatcher.java:494) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Cannot instantiate the coordinator for operator Source: HiveSource-zjdev_xiangliang.users -> SinkConversionToTuple2
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:231) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.attachJobGraph(ExecutionGraph.java:866) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.12.2.jar:1.12.2]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1871) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
    ...
```

try add dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

get another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.Option.builder(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Option$Builder;
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.parser.CommandLineOptions.<clinit>(CommandLineOptions.java:27)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.DynamicParametersConfigurationParserFactory.options(DynamicParametersConfigurationParserFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.DynamicParametersConfigurationParserFactory.getOptions(DynamicParametersConfigurationParserFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.parser.CommandLineParser.parse(CommandLineParser.java:42)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypointUtils.parseParametersOrExit(ClusterEntrypointUtils.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.entrypoint.YarnJobClusterEntrypoint.main(YarnJobClusterEntrypoint.java:89)
```

try to fix conflict about commons-cli:1.3.1 with 1.2:
choose 1.3.1 then error 1;
choose 1.2 then error 2;
add dependency commons-cli 1.4, then error 1.

Comment: You don't need Flink libraries to create a Hive client. Are you creating a fat jar, though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1、commons-cli choose 1.3.1 or 1.4
2、add $hadoop_home/../hadoop_mapreduce/* to yarn.application.classpath
```

Answer (score 0):

i got this error too , when i think i maybe a version conflict ,because i used
hive 3.1.2 version is to high than hadoop 2.7.6 version. i always got error such as guava version conflict and so on
so when i used flink-1.15.0 and link hive with jar flink-sql-connector-hive-3.1.2_2.12-1.15.0.jar  i got  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
resolve: this error it because not found jars please move your hadoop jars
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.,hadoop-common,hadoop-mapreduce-client-common
,hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient and hive-exec-3.1.2.jar to flink lib path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).